What is Glinda whispering to Elphaba?
The iconic poster for the musical Wicked shows Glinda whispering to Elphaba. I've seen many different versions of this, on billboards and on tie-in book editions, etc.
What precisely is Glinda whispering to Elphaba? Is this supposed to be a reference to something that happens in the musical (or the original book)?



I'm aware that she whispers to Elphaba a couple of times in Wicked: The Life and Times of the Wicked Witch of the West, but none of those seem to match the aesthetic here; 

Well, they didn't know, especially after whatever it was had happened to them at tea with Madame Morrible. "Scale down, Elphie," whispered Glinda, "you're making him mad."

and

"Not till now," said Elphaba. Rather smarmy tonight, thought Glinda, and wrenched herself away to climb into the cab. But Elphaba grabbed her by the elbow and pivoted her around. "You can't," she whispered. "We're going to the Emerald City."
"I'm going to the Philosophy Club with my friends-"
"Tonight," hissed Elphaba. "You little idiot, we have no time to waste on sex!"


Also this cover art was adapted from promotional art for the musical. The original cover art was quite different, and did not entail whispers.

@Lexible - Yes, this is a "tie-in edition" where they take new artwork from a related property (usually a film) and slap it back on the original work.

"Hail Hydra..."

The deleted answer should come back. As discussed in the abstract here; https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1053811916304086 Sascha Frühholz] whispering is used to show closeness and promote in group cohesion. Combined with the smile on Elphaba's face, it is clearly an image used to convey an intimate friendship, which is the basis of the book's middle third.

@Jontia - I was much less interested in the aesthetic of why humans whisper to other humans and what that conveys thematically, and far more interested in literally what Glinda is whispering to Elpheba. The deleted question didn't answer any part of that, and in fact claimed (without justification) that the subject matter wasn't important.

@Valorum I understand. But I think the frame challenge presented in the answer is right. The main difference between Wicked and The Wizard of Oz as you might present it to someone only familiar with the original is 'what if the wicked witch and the good witch used to be friends' the cover illustrates that perfectly.

@Jontia - Meh. It seems lazy and reductive, and not a little dismissive. The question is "what", not "why"

@Valorum I would put it the other way around. Assuming the cover has to map to a single scene is reductive and dismissive of the work of the illustrator. Film posters are rarely a single still from the film, a good book cover is no different.

The image here captures the whole of the premise. Sure you could text search the book for the word whispered and quote that bit as an answer, but that doesn't showcase how the cover captures the change in premise between The Wizard of Oz and Wicked.

This would make an excellent answer if you could back it up with a lick of evidence.

While the book may contain a specific scene that resembles the image on the cover, that is most likely a simple co-incidence. The cover image here is not supposed to provide a peek into any specific incident it is supposed to sell you on the idea of the story and get you to come and watch, or buy a copy of, Wicked.
That the image originates with the stage play of Wicked rather than the book further supports this premise. We can assume that it's supposed to sell us on the main points of the play focusing around the relationship between Elphaba and Glinda and their school/university friendship rather than the epic Good Witch/Wicked Witch rivalry from the Wizard of Oz. These points remain important in the book, which makes the cover useable despite the lack of references to the various other arcs that are unique to the written version.
But poster/billboard advertising is much more important to a theatre play than a cover is to a book. The purpose of the advertising is to get you to commit and to give you an idea of what to expect. What we see here is a visualisation of friendship between the two main characters in their youth; the whispered conversations, the wry smile and smooth skin all seek to convey to change to the narrative of the famous original. The image no more has to reference a single scene than a film poster has to be a single still from a movie. The illustrator's job is bigger than that.

"The cover image here is not supposed to provide a peek into any specific incident" - This seems a very bold assertion (and one which would theoretically answer the question fully), but without a lick of evidence to back it up.

"What we see here is a visualisation of friendship between the two main characters in their youth" - Again, a bold assertion without evidence

@Valorum advertising like humour is subjective. You take what you want from it. None of what I've written feels like a difficult stretch requiring unique insight or specific evidence. But feel free to disagree.

@Jontia I think the evidence being asked for is that this is the intended interpretation - e.g. some background to who originated the image, and a quote about what they were trying to represent. Otherwise, it's just your interpretation, which while interesting doesn't really fit the strict Q&A format of the site (we could have lots of answers giving different opinions, and none could be judged "correct").

@IMSoP I understand that, but I think it places the evidential bar too high. Unless we close any slightly off beat Q's to be Word of God only then Occam's Razor, real world information is evidence in itself. This is what advertising is for, this is the main plot of the story. That's why it's on the poster. Equally I can't fault anyone who disagreed with this take. And I'm more than happy to soak up the downvotes for what I feel is a sensible frame challenge answer to a question that is interesting but comes from a focus on fan detail instead of considering the real world.
